# Splitting VUE code for simplicity in multi developer team environment

Tags: html, vue.js

I want to code such as below:

*index.html-*

```
<html>
  <div id="app1">
     <button @click="product-list">Click me</button> 
  </div>
  <div id="app2">
    <button @click="group-list">Click me</button>
  </div>

  <script>
     import product-list from '../components/items.vue'
     import group-list from '../components/groups.vue'
  </script>
</html>
```

*items.vue-*

```
<template id="product-list">
</template>

<template id="add-product">
</template>

<template id="delete-product">
</template>

<template id="edit-product">
</template>

<script>

</script>
```

I want to call external .vue files which contain all it's required templates and it's

individual vue instance in one file. The idea of attempting to do this, is to split the

code for coding in multi developer team environment wherein the code will be

easily readable and multiple coders can also keep working on their individually

assigned code.

for example:- 
*items.vue* - has multiple templates which I want to maintain separately.
add-product, delete-product, edit-product, and more.

*groups.vue* - has multiple templates which I want to maintain separately.
add-group, delete-group, edit-group, and more.

Answer (score 0):

.vue files are single file components (SFC), which means they can only contain one component (one `<template>` and/or one `<script>` and/or one `<style>`).

Also, you are not supposed to put vue code in your index.html, because it is not valid html.

You could simply use subfolders like /groups and /items, then create multiple .vue files like ProductList.vue, AddProduct.vue, etc.

FYI, in the line `import product-list from '../components/items.vue'`, `product-list` is not a valid javascript variable name (can't contain hyphens).